# Change permalinks from post id to post name in Wordpress without using a plug in or getting error 404

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I have a wordpress site and i want to change the permalink structure from post id to post name. I already have 100 posts and do not want to break the old links so i want to redirect them without getting error 404. The thing is i know there are plug ins to do the job for you but i prefer to not use plug ins in my website when i can avoid them! Is there a way to do the whole redirect old links without using a plug in? I read something about editing the htaccess file but I couln't pull it off! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use on this code into your root .htaccess file than permalink change to post name. & collect your old post url than use 301 redirect plugin.

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

or you can help with this site.
https://www.themeconfig.com/wordpress-basic-services/

thank you